# How can I Invoke interactive shell with initial input as SCons Phony target?

Tags: python, scons, yosys

While implementing custom SCons toolchain, I've encounter situation when I need to invoke shell as *Phony* target with initial input already provided, so I can continue to provide input to already invoked command.

Basically, what I want is to declare *Phony* target with desired behaviour:

```py
# ...
def invoke_shell(target, source, env):
    initial_input = '...'
    # Some steps to interactive command with already provided initial_input

shell = env.Command(Alias('some-shell'), [],
    invoke_shell)
env.AlwaysBuild(shell)
```

What I've tried is to write the following *SConstruct* file to cover case without initial input:

```py
# ...
def invoke_yosys(target, source, env):
    return 'yosys'

yosys_shell = env.Command(Alias('yosys-shell'), [],
    invoke_yosys)
env.AlwaysBuild(yosys_shell)
```

So when I invoke `scons -Q yosys-shell` I should get Yosys shell, but in general case it can be any interactive command. What I expect is that shell is invoked interactively, i.e. I can enter command and Yosys shell will interactively execute commands while providing input. But it doesn't work. It exits immediately as if `stdin` is mapped to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use Command() as that's deferred until the tree walk, you want it to run immediately before the rest of the build right?

You'd want to detect the target on the command line and then fire off the command using Execute() or os.system()..

See [here](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#sect-command-line-targets) for info on grabbing the command line targets.